# Display List or Library on another site as WebPart?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list, sharepoint-designer, error

I want to display my list on another site in same site collection. I edit List with SPDesigner, select the view and save it to site gallery. After these steps, I added the view webpart on my another site. Everything is fine before making change the Name of WebPart. I try to edit webpart and change the name from appearence category. I encounterd the error `List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.`

I click the `Go back to site` and the webpart name changed. There is no problem. But I dont understand why error page is coming.

I try to find solution but I could not. Please help!!!

Thank you,

MUhammed KACAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the XSLT List Viewer Web Part using SharePoint Designer. After that you can embed the List View in any desired location within the same site collection.
I wrote a little how-to export the xslt List Viewer Webpart a couple of while ago.
This can be found here http://www.n8d.at/blog/sharepoint-2010/exporting-xslt-list-view-web-part-using-sharepoint-designer/

[image]
<sub>(source: [n8d.at](http://www.n8d.at/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/XSLT-List-Viewer-3.png))</sub>

You also need to choose yes when you export the web part.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested that you use "Content Query" Webpart and pull the list items from the top site.

It supports showing list views across different subsites and top site within a single site collection. If your sharepoint designer view is not something complex and is "just" about showing relevant columns based on certain sort order and filter , then use the content query webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Iwould don't care if it works well except that specific case. There probably not-so-well coded validation over EditorPart done by product team.

Answer (score 0):

Using Soap Webservices you can create a dataview webpart in sharepoint designer to display the contents of another subsite.Very good article here:
[Connect to another library in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/cizi/2010/08/01/connect-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

After you have dataview webpart you can export that into your site web part  gallery.

Hope this helps.