# List unexpected error

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, error

We saved a list as webpart to show this list on other sites or subsites. Now there are two list which can't be open since we saved them as webpart. The webparts are working fine but the list won't open. There is an error message. I checked the log data, but i have no idea how to fix it. 
Here is the information of my log file:

> *10/21/2013 07:59:04.41   w3wp.exe (0x0A58)                           0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Name=Request
>   (GET:http://[site]/Lists/[Listname]/AllItems.aspx)    3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.42    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Site=/  3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.42    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler).
>   Ausführungszeit=14,0007   3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.44    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           General
>     8sl1    High        DelegateControl: Exception thrown while adding control
>   'ASP._controltemplates_metadatanavtree_ascx': Der Wert liegt außerhalb
>   des erwarteten Bereichs.  3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.52    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData).
>   Ausführungszeit=61,5688   3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>   10/21/2013 07:59:04.55    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (DataBinding DataFormWebPart
>   ([Listname])).
>   Ausführungszeit=100,2535  3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>   10/21/2013 07:59:04.56    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  Web Content Management          Publishing
>     e8fx    High        Unable to get a cached list with id
>   '68d0fae2-7c96-41be-b1b3-1ce1211471af' from web
>   '/[site]/[subsite]'   3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.56    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis
>   wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.    bei
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records.GetCachedAllowManualRecordDeclarationSetting(CachedList
>   list, Hashtable siteProperties)     bei
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Controls.DeclareRecordAction.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   bei
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.MonitoredScopeWrapper.RunWithMonitoredScope(Action
>   code)     bei
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Controls.DeclareRecordAction.GetDeclareRecordInfo()
>   bei
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Controls.InPlaceRecordsRibbon.Page_PreRenderComplete(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     bei System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)     bei
>   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(...    3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>   10/21/2013 07:59:04.56*   w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  ...EventArgs e)     bei
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe
>
> 10/21/2013 07:59:04.58    w3wp.exe (0x0A58)
>     0x1E00  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (GET:http://[site]/Lists/[Listname]/AllItems.aspx)).
>   Ausführungszeit=175,804   3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your advice. 
I found a solution for my problem. 
The list was referring to records management site object which it has not been configured. 
I disabled the "In place Records management" in my root site collection features and the list works again.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your getting the list from the correct site ;)

based from the error you have given the webpart is trying to get a list from a specific site but it cannot find it!

> Unable to get a cached list with id
>   '68d0fae2-7c96-41be-b1b3-1ce1211471af' from web '/[site]/[subsite]'
>   3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe

to explain what might be going wrong is:

You have a list in site A that you made into a webpart:

> A (site)

now you want to show it in a subsite of site B

> B (Site) -> c (subsite)

the problem is when you created the webpart you said to not use site A but to use the site its on, so its using site c but the list doesnt exist on site c it exists on site a.

> B (Site) -> c (subsite) -> add webpart that is looking on site C
>   **NOT** A

so in your case you have

> **A** (site) -> contains a List with ID **68d0fae2-7c96-41be-b1b3-1ce1211471af**
>
> **B** (Site) -> **C** (subsite with ID of **3c7d54dd-9f73-4022-bc0d-ca049c3fd2fe**) -> added a webpart that is **looking on site C for list ID 68d0fae2-7c96-41be-b1b3-1ce1211471af**

so to test this create a simple console app, so the list ID could be correct but the site that is referencing is wrong!

this could happen when the new webpart when you created it is referencing the current site its on and not the site that the list originated from!

for a quick test you could use this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yousiteurl"))
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Site name is");
                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                Console.WriteLine("the site ID is");
                Console.WriteLine(web.ID);
                Console.WriteLine();
                getlist(web);
                Console.WriteLine();
                web.Dispose();
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

create this method that is being called from above within the main method for the console app:

```
    private static void getlist(SPWeb web)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List name:");
                Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
                Console.WriteLine("List ID:");
                Console.WriteLine(list.ID);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
        }
    }
```

the above will return all webs that have lists, it will give their ids, you can then see from the error section i highlighted if its in the list, or throw it in a catch statment as its less code and less loops like this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bd7d09d9-541c-4882-8dea-4b8faa14a551/check-to-see-if-list-exists?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

above code will only tell you if its in or not, my code will show you all sites and lists within them,

but the point is, when you created the webpart from the list you missed a setting I think, so instead of it accessing the list from the site you wanted it to reference it is instead referencing from the site your webpart is put on! go through the webpart setup again this time when you come up with a check stating weather you want to keep this list location select yes and not no!

[image]

[Display List or Library on another site as WebPart?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37140/display-list-or-library-on-another-site-as-webpart)