# Display List/Web Part on Another Site with SP2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, aspx

[Apparently it was possible to export a web part and import it on a different site with SP2010.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37140/display-list-or-library-on-another-site-as-webpart)
This does not work anymore for SP2013. I also tried to edit the ***.aspx** directly, but it always throws me the following error:

> List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

The content search web part is able to display data from another site, but can not be utilized like a list web part.

Is there any possibility to insert a list web part on a different site without losing its functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still works and I love it!

You have to get the correct WebId in the exported file. So you have to find the WebId from the source site.

I am **working right now on a step-by-step guide** which will be online by the beginning of next week and will update my answer with the link to the guide. For now I can only help you with this:

```
$SPWeb = get-spweb http://your-url/your-subsite
$SP.Web.Id
```

[image]

Replace the WebId column which is filled with zeros with the correct WebId.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Then you can import the list and add it to your site.

Maybe that is help enough for you.

[image]

**Update 1:**

Page is back online with an [step-by-step guide](https://afrait.com/blog/export-import-eines-webparts-de/).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have admin rights, so no access to the shell. But I hope there's another way to get the web ID.

Comment: It is working here with CEWP, but the page does a reload instantly after pressing the button, but maybe you can fix it. Found the little script here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b30982d-4be0-43a2-b80b-f2bad398c28e/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-web-id?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I suppressed the reload with that solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3527113/4928482
Your solution is perfectly working now. :)

Comment: Nice solution - works as expected :) Many thanks [Patrick](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/24244/patrick) !!

Answer (score 0):

It does still work, but one extra step. You can do your export in SharePoint designer, but you have to mark the web part, either through the GUI or from Designer, as 'Render on Server'. It's in the miscellaneous part of the web part properties. Then when you export the webpart from Designer, it will ask you if you want to keep the webpart attached to the original list.